# Panda keep/ add column that was "lost" during groupby and agg

Tags: python, pandas

Hej guys,

I am working on a cohorts script that shows the CM2 (= Contribution margin 2) development of a Google ad account for each day looking back the last 30 days.

I have a dataframe, based on a last 30 days Campaign Performance Report, that looks like this and goes on for over 1000 rows:

```
 |   Date   |Sale| CM2 |Views|Click|CPC |CTR | CPM |Cost |Data_PullDate
0|2018-09-09|3   |37.44|1436 |77   |0.25|5.36|13.86|19.91|2018-10-09  
1|2018-09-09|0   | 0.00|1359 | 6   |0.29|0.44| 1.31| 1.79|2018-10-09 
2|2018-09-10|0   | 0.00|  98 | 3   |0.38|3.06|11.63| 1.14|2018-10-09 
3|2018-09-10|3   |38.04|2524 |83   |0.30|3.29|10.08|25.46|2018-10-09
```

I group the data by the Date-column and then calculate the sum or mean for the KPI columns with Pandas' agg function:

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(df['Date']).agg({'Sales':['sum'],'CM2':['sum'],'Views':['sum'],'Click':['sum'],'CPC':['mean'],'CTR':['mean'],'CPM':['mean'],'Cost':['sum']})
```

The outcome is as expected the sum and means of the columns by date:

```
    Date  |  Cost | CPM |CTR | Views|CPC |  CM2  |Sale|Click
             sum   mean  mean  sum   mean   sum    sum  sum
2018-09-09|1971.78|19.44|6.27|108821|0.40|4903.63|188 |5585
2018-09-10|1936.36|20.11|5.91| 94401|0.41|4263.38|194 |4914
```

As one can tell from the difference in the column count, from the initial dataframe's columns the column Data_PullDate is missing but this column is crucial for me to proceed with the cohorts.
This column represents the date the data was pulled and is the date the script ran.

How do I keep/ add the column Data_PullDate to the grouped_data dataframe?
Also, how do I keep the initial order of the columns?

Comment: merge it with the original table

Comment: Not sure what kind of values you expect in the column; but if they are all the same you could also do `'Data_PullDate': ['min']`

Comment: @Roelant wow... this is super easy and exactly what I needed.
The Data_PullDate is for all entries the same, therefore min (or max) did what I needed.
Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on your data, but one solution (if `Data_Pulldate` is always the same) would be to add another aggregation

```
'Data_PullDate': ['min']
```

If it differs, I am not sure I understand the dataset - and I would suspect you want to add it as a second column in the `GroupBy` .